# Removing GitHub Profile & Repos from Google Search

Tags: github, google-search, google-search-console

I want to remove my GitHub profile and repos therein from being found via Google search. Researching how to do this, I see it comes down to three possible methods:

1. Adding a robots.txt file
2. Adding meta tag to prevent indexing
3. Removing URL via Google Webmasters

To my understanding, methods 1 and 2 above won't work for a GitHub account, but only works if you own the root domain.

For method 3, first you have to verify ownership of the specified URL by one of the following means:

1. HTML file
2. HTML tag
3. Google Analytics
4. Google Tag Manager
5. Domain name provider

With any of the verification methods mentioned above, I don't see how GitHub supports any of them.

Given these considerations, any ideas on how I can remove my GitHub profile and repos from Google search results?

Comment: Are you talking about GitHub itself, or a site hosted on GitHub Pages?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? It might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You should contact their support team to see if it is possible. Can you explain why you want them hidden in case there is a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 4):

As long as I know, you can't hide your github account from google.

I also found this [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67345) explaining the same thing.

Also check the GitHub's [robots.txt file](https://github.com/robots.txt) for more information